# Customer and Grand Total with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Having some trouble getting MySQL to work with me on this project. I have an Order table that contains Name, OrderTime, Quantity, CoffeeType, and Price. I need to print the customer name once, all orders from that customer, the subtotal for each customer, and the grand total. I tried to do it with two nested while loops, but this results in an infinite loop. The format I am going for is:

```
Customer Name:

Ordered 10/12/13 1 Espresso 2.00

Ordered 10/11/13 1 Espresso 2.00

Customer Subtotal: 4.00

Grand Total 4.00


$all = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM orders ORDERBY name");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
"SELECT *, SUM(Price) as Total FROM orders GROUP BY Name WITH ROLLUP");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "Orders for: " . $row["Name"] . "<br>";
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($all);
        while($data["Name"] === $row["Name"]) {
            echo "On " . $row["OrderTime"] . " ordered " . $row["Quantity"] . " " . $row["CoffeeType"] . " Total: " . asDollars($row["Price"]) . "<br>";
        }
        echo "Customer Total: " . $row["Total"];
        if($row["Name"] === NULL) echo "Grand Total: " . $row["Total"];
}
```

I know that nested while loops might not be the best solution for this. I would know how to do this in LINQ with lambda statements, but I am unsure if MySQL has any of this functionality. Is there any way to fix this code so the above format is achieved? Thanks very  much for your time.

Comment: If it was me, I'd just return a list of items and do the rest in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one query using `group_concat()` like

```
select customer_name,
group_concat(orders) as all_order,
sum(price) as total_price
from Order
group by customer_name
```

Comment: I still need to print all information about each transaction as well. I tried: 

`select Name
group_concat(Name) as all_order,
sum(Price) as total_price
from orders
group by Name`

and it returned an error.

Comment: That's obvious cause you are missing a `,` after `select Name`

Comment: So how would I access the other information? From what I see, this query returns a name, group_concat (with only names since orders didn't work) and sums.

Comment: Post some sample data from the order table.

Comment: `[Name][all_order][subtotal]
[Bob][Bob, Bob][78.10]`

So I can't get any other information from all_order other than name. I tried using order and * in the group_concat parameter but neither work.